# Multiple definition of same class function depending on multiple type of the same inherited class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

Is it possible to do multiple definition of same class function  (polymorphism) depending on multiple type of inherited class:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string.h>
//All base A class
class A{
    public:
        int e = 0;
        virtual int GetE() = 0; //to make A virtual
};
class A_A : public A{
    public:
        A_A(){e=1;}
        virtual int GetE(){return e;}
};
class A_B : public A{
    public:
        A_B(){e=2;}
        virtual int GetE(){return e;}
};
//All base B Class
class B{
    public:
        virtual void ActionOnA(A_A& a){a.e = 100;}
        virtual void ActionOnA(A_B& a){a.e = 200;}
        virtual void ActionOnA(A& a){}
};
class B_A : public B{
    public:
        /*
            B_A as the same behavior of B class but B is virtual
        */
};
class B_B : public B{
    public:
        /*
            B_B do different things on A depending on which A object is passed
        */
        virtual void ActionOnA(A_A& a){a.e += -100;}
        virtual void ActionOnA(A_B& a){a.e += -200;}
        virtual void ActionOnA(A& a){}
};
//now I create a custom A_* class
class A_C : public A{
    public:
        A_C(){e=90;}
        virtual int GetE(){return e;}
};
//Since A_C is never handled anywhere, I must create a new B_* to handle it
//I want it have the behavior of B_A in every A class except for A_C
class B_C : public B_A{
    public:
        virtual void ActionOnA(A_C& a){a.e = 0;}
};

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    std::vector<A*> AllMyA;
    A_A Object1;
    A_B Object2;
    A_C Object3;
    
    AllMyA.push_back(&Object1);
    AllMyA.push_back(&Object2);
    AllMyA.push_back(&Object3);
    
    B_A test;
    for(A* a : AllMyA){
        test.ActionOnA(*a);
        std::cout << a->GetE() << '\n';
    }
    /*
        Result should be :
            100
            200
            90
        Result is :
            1
            2
            90
    */
    
    AllMyA.clear();
    
    A_A Object4;
    A_B Object5;
    A_C Object6;
    
    AllMyA.push_back(&Object4);
    AllMyA.push_back(&Object5);
    AllMyA.push_back(&Object6);
    
    B_B test2;
    for(A* a : AllMyA){
        test2.ActionOnA(*a);
        std::cout << a->GetE() << '\n';
    }
    /*
        Result should be :
            100
            200
            0
        Result is :
            1
            2
            90
    */
}
```

This example don't work, it always call ActionOnA(A& a). Can someone explain me how could I make it work knowing the fact I can't do static_cast because I don't know which type of A_* my A ptr is?
Isn't exist a better way of working? Maybe with template?

Comment: You can use `dynamic_cast`

Comment: @ChrisMM No, it don't do the trick since I'm supposed to don't know what inherited type of A it is (Maybe later, this code will be in a lib and user will be able to redefine their own A and B class).

Comment: I don't think you really understand the difference between runtime type and compile type. As Karek mentioned, in the case of `ActionOnA`, it's based on the static (compile time) type; not the runtime type. So you need a `dynamic_cast` to call the appropriate functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a big difference between the functions `ActionOnA` and `GetE`; `GetE` is a virtual function, thus, the compiler writes down a jump to the corresponding function in the object's virtual function table, which is determined in run-time.

However, when we look at ActionOnA, the compiler need to *"know"* what function to write down on compile time (it is not virtual!), therefore, it puts the most suitable function overload, which is `ActionOnA(A*)`. The same problem will occur with templates, which are determined at compile time, therefore, it won't choose the overload according to its run-time type.

As [ChrisMM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10686048/chrismm) wrote, you can try to make `dynamic_cast` that may fail. But it seems to me that the problem is a bit different:

You want to have a dynamic function in A which makes the valid operation on run-time:

```
virtual void updateE(bool shouldResetE);
```

In A_A:

```
void updateE(bool shouldResetE) final
{
    this->E = shouldResetE ? 100 : this->E - 100;
}
```

Also, a strong recommendation is to use both `override` and `final` specifiers, since it helps catching errors in compile time (`override` will warn when not properly overriding a function, `final` will warn when trying to override this function on inheriting classes). If A_* are not meant to be inherited from, specify it using `final`.